Fatest query to lock down a snapshot in MySQL for REPEATABLE READ transaction
Per the MySQL documentation, for a transaction with the REPEATABLE READ isolation level:

Consistent reads within the same transaction read the snapshot established by the first read.

I want to establish a snapshot for a table as fast as possible. I know SELECT * FROM <the table> LIMIT 1 works, but even one single row of the table is large, such a query takes a long time too. So I wonder if there is even a faster way to do the first read of a table.

Please consider posting TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; so we can get an idea of the effort that might be required to read when you have no WHERE to select anything, just a blind table read.  Also please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT (your query); so we can see what the optimizer did to arrive at any result displayed.

Do select 1 instead of select *, so you aren't actually reading the table data?
If that is still too slow, and you know some maximum number of rows, you can do:
select 1 from yourtable limit 1 offset 100000000

Though do try it out with your data; possibly that isn't going to be any faster than just:
select count(*) from yourtable

(I was going to suggest doing LIMIT 0, but in my testing with mariadb 11.4, it doesn't establish the snapshot (a bug?) so presumably even if it works with your version of mysql, it may not continue to do so.)

It's InnoDB behavior, which is still mostly the same between MySQL and MariaDB (but may not be forever). If you do a query that doesn't match any rows, it doesn't count as a read and doesn't create a snapshot. Similarly, SELECT ... WHERE false does not create a snapshot.

Your example of SELECT 1 still reads rows, so I don't think it's an optimization. You can confirm it's reading rows by using SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%'.

@BillKarwin re SELECT 1, I wasn't sure what the concern actually was with "even one single row of the table is large", sounded like maybe transfer time was an issue.
